# Sum numerical values returned by functions without creating new columns/rows for them

Tags: excel

I have a following problem: let's assume that I have the following four rows in the column A:

```
Alice: $5
Bob: $12
Alice: $23
Bob: $4
```

What I want to do is sum $ values for Alice only. I came up with this function that extracts numerical values from a single row:

```
=if(isnumber(find("Alice", A1)),right(A1, (len(A1) - find("$",A1))),0)
```

This way, a row gives me a $ value if it's Alice row or 0 if it's not. It's done in a way that would easily allow it to be reused for Bob if I need to.
The problem is that normally i'd just use the `sum` function for summing up all the data in a column (`=sum(A1:A4)`), but using it for a function in this way:

```
=sum((if(isnumber(find("Alice", A1)),right(A1, (len(A1) - find("$",A1))),0)):(if(isnumber(find("Alice", A4)),right(A4, (len(A4) - find("$",A4))),0)))
```

apparently doesn't work. How should I do it? There's one more requirement, though - I can't create any column for storing values returned by those functions (if I could, I'd just create four new rows in, say, B1:B4 and just `sum` them).

Comment: This is generally accomplished using [Array Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).  But, in this case I couldn't get it to work.  I think your formula is too complicated.  You will probably need to resort to [tag:VBA] to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example the dataset is the named range "TestNames"

SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERROR(FIND("Alice",TestNames)),0,ROWS(TestNames)^0) * (RIGHT(TestNames,LEN(TestNames) - FIND("$",TestNames))))

This is a regular formula and does not need to be input with CSE